# Formatting Date on Html.TextBoxFor - other solutions not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

Using EF-generated classes, here's my metadata class:

```
    [DisplayName("Approved Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
                            HtmlEncode = false,
                            NullDisplayText = "", 
                            DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public object ApprovedDate{ get; set; }
```

The view:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Standard)%>
```

The editor:

```
<%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApprovedDate)%>
```

The DateTime.ascx:

```
<%string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;%>
<%string id = name.Replace(".", "_");%>

<div class="clear">
    <div class="editor-label"><%:Html.LabelFor(model => model)%></div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)%>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=id%>").datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Nothing seems to work.  I have to maintain the binding, so I don't want to do raw HTML.

All the date fields output with the same formatting, which includes the Time.

3/12/2009 12:00:00AM

What it needs to be is

3/12/2009

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using `<%= Html.TextBox(null, string.Format("{0:d}", Model))%>` .  Seems to work, and retains the bindings.